# how to use ajax to update a particular div after the click of a submit?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php    
$short_des="Harry Potter is a series of fantasy novels"; //initially short_description has this value
echo '<span><p>About:</p> '.$short_des.'</span>'; //initially i am printing short_des here but after cick of submit i want to update it
echo '<form class="make_long_form" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="make_descrip_long" method="post" name="make_descrip_long" value="'.$post_read_more['id'].'">';
    echo '<input type="submit" id="read_more_button" value="Show more">'; //this is the submit form
echo '</form>';
if(isset($_POST['make_descrip_long'])){
$short_description = "Harry Potter is a series of fantasy novels written by British author J. K. Rowling."; //after the click of submit i want to update the value of short_description and update it in the about echo above
                        }   
?>
```

I think i have to use ajax to update the value of short_des in the echo. Help.

Comment: For this kind of action, you could just javascript - there's no need for ajax

Comment: can you please tell me how should i do it?

Comment: if you are searching to load the content dinamically from another page, i just answered you on how to do this using jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try this:

ajax function:

```
function loadDiv(url, element){
    $.post(url, {}, function(res){
        myDiv.html(res);
    }
}
```

url: is a string that rapresent the page where the data that you want to put in the div is located.

element: is the div you want to update, in jQuery u can pass it with his id selector:

```
var element = $("#divID");
```

the {} are a json object that will be passed to the url page as post.

in the res variable you get the response of the request, in html.